# No subspace of $R_{usual}$ is homeomorphic to $\omega_1$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Where $\omega_1$ is defined as a subset of an uncountable well-order W s.t $\omega_1 = \{ \alpha \in W: \ pred(\alpha)$ is countable} with the following properties:
1. $\omega_1$ is uncountable

2. For every $\alpha \subseteq \omega_1,\  pred(\alpha) \subseteq \omega_1$
3. Every countable subset of $\omega_1$ is bounded above.

$pred(\alpha) = \{ x \in W: x < \alpha \}$

Attempt at solution: 
I'm really confused about this question, different subsets of $R$ will not be homeomorphic to $\omega_1$ for different reasons, for example The $\Bbb{N}$ with the usual topology are discrete but we can show $\omega_1$ is not so they can't be homeomorphic, but then there can be so many different subsets. Another possibility id that we can show $min(\omega_1)$ is clopen but the usual topology has no non trivial clopen sets. 
I would really appreciate help, with detailed explanation if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is second-countable, its subspaces are second-countable metric spaces, hence separable. If such a homeomorphism exists, then $\omega_1$ is separable. Let $E$ be the countable dense subset in $\omega_1$. Then
$$
\operatorname{pred}(\sup E) = \bigcup_{\alpha\in E} \operatorname{pred}(\alpha).
$$
Hence $\operatorname{pred}(\sup E)$ is countable. That means $\sup E \in \omega_1$. But then it's immediate successor is in $\omega_1$, so $\{\alpha>\sup E\}$ is a non-empty open set in $\omega_1$, not containing any point of $E$. That's a contradiction. Hence no subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\omega_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the family $S$ of all successor ordinals<sup>1</sup> in $\omega_1$ is discrete. (In fact each element of $S$ is isolated in $\omega_1$.<sup>2</sup>) If some subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ were homeomorphic to $\omega_1$, then there would be an uncountable discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (corresponding to $S$).

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable, every uncountable $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ subset must have a [condensation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_point), that is, there is an $x \in A$ such that $U \cap A$ is uncountable for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$.<sup>3</sup>  In particular, no uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be discrete.

Therefore no subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\omega_1$.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>$a \in \omega_1$ is a *successor ordinal* if there is a $b \in \omega_1$ such that $a = \min \{ x \in \omega_1 : b < x \}$. Here $b$ is the *predeccessor* of $a$, and $a$ is the *successor* of $b$.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>If $a \in S$, let $b \in \omega_1$ be the predecessor of $a$, and let $c \in \omega_1$ be the successor of $a$. Then $(a,c)$ is open in $\omega_1$, and it is easy to see that $(a,c) = \{ b \}$.</sub>
<sup>3</sup> <sub>Fix a countable base $\mathcal{B}$ for $\mathbb{R}$. Consider $\mathcal{B}_0 = \{ U \in \mathcal{B} : | U \cap A | \leq \aleph_0 \}$. If $W = \bigcup \mathcal{B}_0$, then $W \cap A = \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{B}_0} ( U \cap A )$ is countable, being a countable union of countable sets. So $A \setminus W$ is nonempty. Given any $x \in A \setminus W$, if $U \in \mathcal{B}$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then as $x \notin W = \bigcup \mathcal{B}_0$ it must be that $U \notin \mathcal{B}_0$, and so $U \cap A$ must be uncountable, by definition of $\mathcal{B}_0$. It follows that every open neighborhood of $x$ has uncountable intersection with $A$.</sub>